# Toggle Posts in wordpress using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops, toggle

I am trying to do something I have not seen before in wordpress. Basically, when you arrive at the blog, a title, thumbnail and an excerpt is displayed. When a toggle button is pushed, the post should slide down to reveal the content. (`<?php the_content(); ?>`)

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('span.play a').click(function() {
               if ($('.toggleSection').is(":hidden"))
               {
                    $('.toggleSection').slideDown("slow");
               } else {
                    $('.toggleSection').slideUp("slow");
               }
               return false;
          });
     });
```

It works perfectly! However; because the toggle is placed within the wordpress loop, whenever the toggle button is pressed, all of the posts toggle open. For instance, If I have 10 posts on a page, and one toggle button is clicked, all of the toggles open. Here is my WP loop:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="post" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                       <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'mainimg' ); ?>
                        <span class="play"><a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#comments').toggle();"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/play.png" width="30" height="36" alt="Play Video"></a></span>
                    </div>


                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <h3>Posted in: <span><?php the_category(', ') ?>  </span>On: <span><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?></span></h3>

                    <div class="entry">
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>   
                    </div> <!-- entry -->

                    <div class="toggleSection">
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?> </p>
                    </div>



                </div> <!-- .post -->

              <?php endwhile; ?>
```

What you are seeing above, is that when span.play a is clicked, the togglesection slides down and reveals the content. When any single toggle is selected, all of the content appears. I would like it so each toggle is unique within the WP loop, and only reveals that entry's content. Any ideas?

You can see a demo of my work so far here: http://vitaminjdesign.com/littlewindow/ Press the play button over the thumbnails to toggle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slim down your current code and fix the issue with toggling all of them like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('span.play a').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.post').find('.toggleSection').slideToggle();
     return false;
  });
});
```

This goes up to the `.post` element using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) then does a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `.toggleSection` only inside *that* `.post`.  Then the toggle code can be condensed down to just a [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) call.  The above centers around using the current element, `$(this)`, then traversing to find the element(s) you're after using the [tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: Nick! You have answered a bunch of my questions, and your always spot on. THANKS!