# Toggle excerpt and content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle

I've seen this link: [Toggle Posts in wordpress using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687638/toggle-posts-in-wordpress-using-jquery) but it's unfortunately not doing what I want. I have a custom post type. What I want is to have an excerpt with "Read More" link. I got that. But I want the Read More link to toggle/slideToggle the full content within the article. Also have a "read less" link that will go back to showing the excerpt.

Edit: Here is the script I got working...can anyone tell me if this is too much. It works now, but I don't know if there is an easier way.

```
    $(function() {
    $('.content').hide()
  $('a.read').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.tenant').find('.content').slideDown('fast');
     $('.excerpt').hide()
     return false;
  });
  $('a.read-less').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.tenant').find('.excerpt').slideToggle('fast');
     $('.content').hide()
     return false;
  });
});
```

Then my query:

```
    <?php query_posts('post_type=tenants'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article class="tenant">
        <div class="tenant-header">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'left')); ?>

             <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
            </div>
     <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="" class="read">Read More</a>  </div>
     <div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?><a href="" class="read-less">Read Less</a></div>
     </article>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

EDIT AGAIN:
When multiple posts are in, and you hit "read more" the text from the other post disappear :-/  So i guess this "almost" the right code

Comment: But, did you *try* to adapt that code? Helpful guide: [ask]

Comment: Yeah for about 1.5 hours before I gave up. :( jQuery isn't my strongest skill.

Comment: No problem, but show *your code*. Specify *what* is not working. And read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), nice examples there. You can [edit] the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you were close, but using `$('.excerpt').hide();` will hide all elements in the page with class `excerpt` that's why you need to reference the clicked element and find the appropriate content inside the article to show/hide:

```
 $(function () {
     $('.content').hide();
     $('a.read').click(function () {
         $(this).parent('.excerpt').hide();
         $(this).closest('.tenant').find('.content').slideDown('fast');
         return false;
     });
     $('a.read-less').click(function () {
         $(this).parent('.content').slideUp('fast');
         $(this).closest('.tenant').find('.excerpt').show();
         return false;
     });
 });
```