# Toggle excerpt/content inside Ajax Load More

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using [Infinite Scroll plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/), trying to have only excerpts displayed on load; then, with a click, the rest of the content load.

The PHP:

```
<div class="tenant"> <li<?php if (! has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo ' class="no-img"'; } ?>>
   <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150));
   }?>
   <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<div class ="post-author"> <?php  the_author_link ();  ?> </div><br>
<div class ="excerpt-posts">   <?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="" class="read">Read More</a></div><br>
<div class= "postcontent">   <?php the_content(); ?></div> <br>
<?php the_date(); ?> 
<div class ="post-category-2"><?php the_category(); ?> </div>
</li>
</div>
```

I think this should be pretty straightforward (cf. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843898/toggle-excerpt-and-content-using-jquery)) but it won't work -- for some reason I can't target any elements that load inside the plugin. I *think* I need to have an event that fires only after the plug-in loads (so document_ready) isn't doing the trick. But I am totally stumped.

Put really simply why doesn't this code

```
$('#ajax-load-more' ).on(function(){
         $('.postcontent').hide();
});
```

hide the content??

Comment: Have you tried using `$(document).on()` a.k.a delegation for dynamic elements?

Comment: Yeah -- still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You `on` does not have a event. And where is the element with the id `ajax-load-more` ?

```
$('#ajax-load-more').on('click', function(){
         $('.postcontent').hide();
});
```